# Moodle data folder error

Tags: web-server, moodle

I am trying to set up an instance of Moodle on Amazon EC2 for a Uni project. I follow the installation tutorial to the "T" but when I try to access the url, all I get is this:

Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

```
The problem seems to be in the folder where the data is supposed to go, not the actual root of Moodle.
```

My dataroot is /home/username/moodledata, and of course I have set this up in the config file

```
CFG->dataroot = '/home/username/moodledata';
```

As for the permissions, I have set them up like this:

```
chmod 0707 /home/username/moodledata
chown http /home/username/moodledata
```

Comment: Try `0776` for permissions.

Comment: @NathanC Did this, but to no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of things you didn't follow the appropriate installation instructions for Moodle. I don't think your moodledata should be in your computer's home.

Ask Moodle. Did you follow the step by step instructions provided by moodle.org?

If you want a simple one-click install of moodle like Gimp, Libreoffice, or Blender, you should first of all get a website. Search for a web host  who mentions Moodle as part of the package. Choose your web host wisely, and don't commit yourself to more than a monthly payment. It shouldn't cost more than a few dollars a month.

Of course the Moodle package is free and open source, but it's possible to be charged a small fortune for having moodle serviced. Not much for a large establishment such as a university or college, but a lot for a state school or small individual business starting up.

Comment: Your assertion that the home directory location might be the culprit is rather vague. Such remarks are better suited for comments, once you have sufficient rep.